# California Travel for five people

Tags: family, california

Hi my family and I have never been to California and we would just like to take roughly 10 days to visit some places.
We have found an agency that organizes trip along the coast from San fransisco to los angeles, pretty nice.
I am wondering what specific agencies you guys usually plan your trip with? Preferrably those who don't have you spend half of your time on the bus.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As there are many thousands of agencies worldwide of varying quality, speciality, affordability, and so forth, the Stack Exchange Q&A format is very ill-suited to recommending or reviewing them. Many travelers, of course, would recommend that you not book a tour to begin with, and travel independently. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on the purpose of Stack Exchange and the kinds of questions we can entertain here.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a travel book or check one out from the library on California.  Rent a car and you can then see the things you want, without being tied down to a specific tourist plan/schedule.  Plan on a couple days in San Francisco, a couple in Los Angeles, and driving to / from SF to LA, stay on State Highway 1 as much a possible going to LA as it hugs the coastline, and some nice places to visit on the way - Hearst Castle, San Simeon, Solvang, etc.   On the way back, fast and boring = Interstate 5; semi-fast = US 101.

Comment: Alternatively, the drop fee for one-way car rentals SF/LA is often zero, and you can leave from LA instead of returning.